# django rest framework parser returns before all statements are executed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `django` and `django-rest-framework` at the latest versions available on the `stable` channel on `pipy` - though, the issue is reproducible on older codebases (`django` version `2.x`) as well.

The issue is when I try to define a custom parser (as per [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)) and an example that illustrates the issue is shown below:

```py
import logging

import json
import jsonschema
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

log = logging.getLogger('logger')

class JSONCustomParser(JSONParser):

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        data = super(JSONCustomParser, self). \
            parse(stream, media_type, parser_context)
        try:
            # these are executed normally
            a = 1
            b = 2

            # problematic bits: un-comment either of these and execution ends early.
            # data = json.load(stream.read())
            # data = json.load("{}")
            # data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
            # auth_name = str(parser_context['request'].auth.application)

            # sample commands not executed if they are *after* the above and either if them is
            # un-commented
            a = a + a
            b = a + 2
        except ValueError:
            log.error("Value error")
        except Exception as generic_exception:
            log.error(str(generic_exception))
        else:
            return data
```

And a very simple test view that you can use:

```py
class TestView(APIView):
    """
    Simple test view to test the parser
    """
    parser_classes = (JSONCustomParser,)
    permission_classes = ()

    def post(self, request):
        content_length = request.META['CONTENT_LENGTH']

        return Response({'received': content_length})
```

I assume the two `stream` consume operations force a return, although not too sure since the stream is consumed by `JSONParser` anyway in the `super` call... However, I am not certain why the others pose an issue...

Comment: Install `pudb` with `pip install pudb`.  Then put this line before `a=1`.  `import pudb;  pudb.set_trace()`.  Debuggers rock.

Comment: Your commented out lines are going to raise exceptions. Specifically, the json.load calls. Check the json library docs for correct usage of load vs loads https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage

Comment: @jimijimjim I see thanks, `loads` works - but the problem is when such an exception is thrown nothing is shown in the error outputs and the response returned as normal with a `200` OK response. As for debuggers, I use them @ross-rogers and yes they are awesome :) -  I've been running this in the `jetbrains` debugger inside PyCharm but does nothing as the code does not raise any (visible) exceptions... I've updated the code to catch all exceptions but it still does not enter there in debug mode...